# WebBrowser GetElementBy Index Possible?

Tags: c#, facebook

I need to click on **Facebook Comment Like Button** by **Index** ie indexing "word" from top of the page.

All I want to do is, go to any Fb post and like second indexed comment (*after Post like button*)

There are lots of like buttons with same properties
we can even do with fb api -https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/Comment/
but I don't have any idea on how  HTTP POST works?

For example- https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151684853020975&set=a.116551875974.100522.7961985974&type=1&comment_id=13707892&offset=0&total_comments=1530

Here I want to make automate to like Comment (*why are ur pictures so blurry*) made by **Barb Close** which is on second index for word "like"

Or if there is any way to do it, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to populate that through jquery by using the class selector, and then calling the .click() method for the same dom element you populated.

Comment: No i havn't ,I know its possible on autoit,Imacros... I dont have idea how to use class item,want to know if its possible in c#.thanks for comment